# $A, B, C$ $IID$ $geometric(p);$ $E[\frac{A - 2B + C}{A}]$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I know how to do all the steps but I am stuck when calculating $E[\frac{1}{A}]$. Any properties of the geometric distribution (i.e apart from solving using the pmf) to solve this?

And for people who are perplexed by the title and less by the problem:

,,
A
,
B
,
C
  are random variables that follow the geometric distribution with parameter 
p
. They are all Independent and Identically Distributed (i.e 
I
I
D
). Based on the given information, solve for $E[\frac{A - 2B + C}{A}]$

Comment: It took me $13$ minutes to understand your question. You may post it at puzzling.stackexchange.com with tag `riddle`.

Comment: What was so hard to understand? $A, B, C$ are random variables that follow the geometric distribution with parameter $p$. They are all Independent and Identically Distributed (i.e $IID$). Based on the given information, solve for $E[\frac{A-2B+C}{A}]$.

Comment: As I said, I finally understood it. But it would be much better if you put the contents of this comment to the body of the question.

Comment: [Asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)

Comment: How is this hard to understand? If you have read any undergraduate probability text book then you know exactly what IID means, what geometric(p) means and, by lord, if you don't understand the expectation part then I am not sure what you are doing on this part of the site.

Comment: I removed the [tag:geometric-probability] tag. Please read the tag descriptions when using tags.